# Error scraping BACnet points (VOLTTRON)

Tags: volttron

When running the BACnet Proxy and MasterDriver agents, I am getting ERROR DURING SCRAPE (Class: object Code:unknownObject). Does this error indicate an incorrect device id or configuration file (csv file with the point names)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is either a bad device address (which could cause a csv to device mismatch if a device exists at the wrong address) or a problem with your csv file.

Usually it's going to be a problem with the csv file.

Comment: I just saw the response to the "Bacnet device not identifying pointName" post, and realized I had used the full device address <ADDRESS>/<NETMASK>:<PORT> instead of the address that showed up in the scan. So the error was with the device address. Upon changing the address, the BACnet Proxy agent worked!